# How should I go about finding convergence/divergence of these two series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2^n \over 3^n +1}  $$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n^4 \over 4^n} $$

The first one I think could be a geometric series, but the +1 in the denominator is confusing me. For both I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know which test for convergence/divergence I'm supposed to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the first series try the limit comparison test with $b_n=(\frac{2}{3})^n$, and we know that converges as it is a geometric series with $|r|<1$.

For the second series, the ratio test should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but what makes you go to the ratio test before any of the other test for the second one?

Comment: Because the series has the transcendental function $4^n$ , and whenever you see those functions, the ratio test is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Note that $\frac{2^n}{3^n+1}\le  \frac{2^n}{3^n} $
2. As the usual method, the ratio test.

Comment: That inequality is false. $\frac {2^n}{3^n + 1} \leq \frac {2^n}{3^n}$ is true though.

Comment: @BradyGilg: Oops! Thanks.